Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/auth/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
Hi I am using NestJs to build Api endpoint and NextJs for Authentication system I got this error when submit a form form Nextjs:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/auth/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
 API END POINT: http://localhost:3001/auth/register
const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof RegisterSchema>) => {
    console.log(values);
    setError("");
    setSuccess("");
    startTransition(() => {
      register(values).then((data) => {
        setError(data.error);
        setSuccess(data.success);
      });
    });
  };

<Form {...form}>
    <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-2">
       ...
    </form>
</Form>

Please help me to fix this error! Thanks

please do a little research first

The issue may be because your frontend (running on http://localhost:3000) is trying to make a request to your backend API (running on http://localhost:3001). Since they are on different origins, the browser blocks the request due to the CORS policy.
To fix this, open the main.js file in your NestJS app and modify the bootstrap() function as follows:


async function bootstrap() {
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
    methods: 'GET,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    credentials: true,
  });

  await app.listen(3001);
 }

 void bootstrap();



This should tell your backend to accept requests from your frontend without being blocked. You will need to restart your NestJS application for the changes to take effect.
